# JSON Deserializer not working for nested object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have an application that serializes an object and sends a JSON string value as below.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public int MessageState { get; set; }
    public object Message { get; set; }
    public object HeaderId { get; set; } 
}

public class Message
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }       
}

Rootobject ro = new Rootobject();
ro.HeaderId = "HID";
ro.MessageState = 0;
ro.Message = new Message() { FName = "john", LName = "Doe", Address = "123456" };

string x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro);
```

This `x` value is sent to another application and it is deserialized as below.

```
public class Rootobject1
{
    public int MessageState { get; set; }
    public object Message { get; set; }
    public object HeaderId { get; set; }
}

public class Message1
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

var y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject1>(receivedMsg);
```

Here the nested object is not getting deserialized for me and is just a `JObject`.

[image: deserializedobj]

How can I deserialize the nested object? Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: Name the class with the number `Message1` and declare the variable `x`, `y` without an understandable, meaningful name is not a good coding practice.

Comment: The objects aren't nested at all. There's no reason for the deserializer to construct a `Message` object when the code tells it to just create an `object`. The deserializer is working fine, as all .NET developers, including you, can verify. StackOverflow is an ASP.NET Core application

Comment: `it just a JObject.` that's the expected, in fact logical behavior. Since the application didn't require any specific type, the deserializer creates a dynamic JObject instance that provides access to the properties and nested objects inside that attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the library tries to deserialize the message it does not know what type it should be. The Json will just be a tree of properties, there is nothing to indicate that `Message` should be deserialized to a `Message1`. Json will inspect the `Rootobject1` to figure out the various types it should use, but if you only have `object`-property there is no type information to go on.

There are a few solutions

#### Use the actual type

```
public Message1 Message { get; set; }
```

This is by far the simplest and best way to handle the problem if your object model allows it.

#### [Specify type name handling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm)

```
string jsonTypeNameAll = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stockholder, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
})
```

This makes the serializer emit a `$type="<typename>"` property that it can use to reconstruct the correct type. But I would warn against this, by default it includes the full namespace, to it makes renaming and moving types difficult, and it can result in security problems. System.Text.Json uses attributes to specify the type name, and that is an approach I much prefer.

#### Parse the json by hand

You can use [JsonTextReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/readjsonwithjsontextreader.htm) to parse the json tree and do whatever you want with it. This allow for a high degree of flexibility, but is the most cumbersome to use.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the reason that defines the `Message` property in `Rootobject1` as an `object` type as you know the data structure.

The quick way to resolve this is to define `Message` with `Message1` type.

```cs
public class Rootobject1
{
    public int MessageState { get; set; }
    public Message1 Message { get; set; }
    public object HeaderId { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you may look to convert the `JObject` to the `Message1` type.

```cs
var message = ((JObject)y.Message).ToObject<Message1>();
```

Comment: The first approach is the more efficient one, avoiding unnecessary casts.